# In universe are multiple levels or instances of the Matrix called Matrices or Matrixes?

Tags: the-matrix, languages

The word 'Matrices' to me feels too close to the [mathematical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) than the [constructed reality](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Matrix). While the English plural can be applied to imported words, even if [they have Latin or other origins](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/the-many-plurals-of-octopus-octopi-octopuses-octopodes).

Which, if any, is most commonly used inside the Matrix films?

Comment: The Matrix is a proper noun, so proper plural needn’t follow the regular plural form; it would largely be be a matter of preference. For example, the machines could even decide the proper plural Matrixen, is the right plural form.

Comment: I'm not answering, because I haven't seen *The Matrix Resurrections*, nor thoroughly searched through the other films, but at least in *The Matrix Reloaded*, The Architect, who repeatedly refers to the six versions of the matrix (at about 1:50 through 1:58 into the film), always refers to "the matrix" as singular, never plural. Referring to it in that way seems analogous to referring to a hardware system as singular, even though you might have loaded multiple versions of an operating system on the hardware over time.

Comment: I'm still partial to "matryoshki".

Answer (score 6):

In brief, we don't know. At no point in the films, nor in any of the extant scripts or script versions, nor in any of the additional materials, tie-in comics or viral webgames are the earlier Matrices (Matrixes?) referred to in plural form.

That being said, it may interest you that *Simulacra and Simulation* by Jean Baudrillard ([the book in which Neo keeps his disks hidden](https://preview.redd.it/mwjghcjpkddz.png?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=5e507fad9c3e8f87dda811ea8e5892cbbd82416d)) does have a glancing reference to this;

> ***“The real ... is produced from miniaturized
> cells, matrices, and memory banks, models of control** – and it can be
> reproduced an indefinite number of times from these.  It no longer
> needs to be rational, because it no longer measures itself against
> either an ideal or negative instance.  It is no longer anything but
> operational.”*

---

Out of universe, the co-writer of The Matrix Resurrections persistently refers to the earlier films as the "*Matrixes*".

> "It's more about the creative concept of some of the choreography and
> backing them up with stuff. **Other than the Matrixes, most of their
> stuff...what makes [Lana] so great is she directs her own action.
> We've had second unit directors on some of the Matrixes just because
> of the logistics involved.** But of late, and especially on Matrix 4,
> she's directing her own action. The second units for them are mostly
> establishing shots, the B-sides of the some of the compositions for
> some locations. But Lana, she does her own action. She weaves it into
> the main unit stuff, which is why their stuff looks so good."
>
> <sub><sup>[Chad Stahelski & David Leitch Tease Involvement in 'Matrix 4': "Coming Back with a Vengeance"](https://collider.com/matrix-4-update-chad-stahelski-david-leitch/)</sup></sub>